# How to parse XML with nested nodes of the same name?

Tags: xml, parsing, go

I'm new to Golang and parsing XML with nested nodes of the same name is too difficult to me. This is a XML pulled from a third party API:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
    <gesmes:subject>Reference rates</gesmes:subject>
    <gesmes:Sender>
        <gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
    </gesmes:Sender>
    <Cube>
        <Cube time="2019-01-28">
            <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.1418"/>
            <Cube currency="JPY" rate="124.94"/>
            <Cube currency="BGN" rate="1.9558"/>
        </Cube>
        <Cube time="2019-01-25">
            <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.1346"/>
            <Cube currency="JPY" rate="124.72"/>
            <Cube currency="BGN" rate="1.9558"/>
        </Cube>
    </Cube>
</gesmes:Envelope>
```

I need to parse it so I have an output like this:

```
&{Rates:[{Currency:USD Rate:1.1418 Date:2019-01-28} {Currency:JPY Rate:124.94 Date:2019-01-28} {Currency:BGN Rate:1.9558 Date:2019-01-28} {Currency:USD Rate:1.1346 Date:2019-01-25} {Currency:JPY Rate:124.72 Date:2019-01-25} {Currency:BGN Rate:1.9558 Date:2019-01-25}]}
```

And here's my code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)


type Rate struct {
    Currency  string `xml:"currency,attr"`
    Rate      string `xml:"rate,attr"`
    Date    string `xml:"time,attr"`
}

type Rates struct {
    Rates []Rate `xml:"Cube>Cube>Cube"`
}

func main() {
    v := &Rates{}
    if err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(src), v); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n\n", v)
}

const src = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
    <gesmes:subject>Reference rates</gesmes:subject>
    <gesmes:Sender>
        <gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
    </gesmes:Sender>
    <Cube>
        <Cube time="2019-01-28">
            <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.1418"/>
            <Cube currency="JPY" rate="124.94"/>
            <Cube currency="BGN" rate="1.9558"/>
        </Cube>
        <Cube time="2019-01-25">
            <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.1346"/>
            <Cube currency="JPY" rate="124.72"/>
            <Cube currency="BGN" rate="1.9558"/>
        </Cube>
    </Cube>
</gesmes:Envelope>`
```

I'm out of ideas how to insert `time` attribute into Rates object. Any help would be appreciated.

Here it is in golang [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5NhJ3PUcjOs)

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be done with just using tags, but it certainly can be done with a custom unmarshaler (https://play.golang.org/p/2IGeJEyP98z).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a custom [`xml.Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshaler) to get the results you want.

```
type Rate struct {
    Currency string `xml:"currency,attr"`
    Rate     string `xml:"rate,attr"`
    Date     string `xml:"time,attr"`
}

type Rates struct {
    Rates RateList `xml:"Cube>Cube"`
}

type RateList []Rate

func (ls *RateList) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    date := start.Attr[0].Value

    for {
        tok, err := d.Token()
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                return nil
            }
            return err
        }

        if se, ok := tok.(xml.StartElement); ok {
            rate := Rate{Date: date}
            if err := d.DecodeElement(&rate, &se); err != nil {
                return err
            }

            *ls = append(*ls, rate)
        }
    }
}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/2IGeJEyP98z)

Comment: How to get Entire text from this? `<claims>
  <claim>
   <claim-text>ABC
    <claim-text>PQR</claim-text>
    <claim-text>Xyz
     <claim-text>A</claim-text>
     <claim-text>B</claim-text>
     <claim-text>C</claim-text>
    </claim-text>
   </claim-text>
  </claim>
  <claim>
   <claim-text>PPP
    <claim-text>ZZZ</claim-text>
    <claim-text>MMM</claim-text>
   </claim-text>
  </claim>
</claims>
`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with mkopriva's answer, but cannot comment so I'm adding a reply.

Make sure that you either trust the XML, or that you validate/sanitize it beforehand, with something like [XSD](https://github.com/metaleap/go-xsd). This should be done for both security reasons, as well as to be able to look back and see if the data you "Unmarshalled" is correct, because when you're processing huge amounts of XML, some of it is bound to be broken.